# mathbbol and Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: font-metrics

Hello everybody I am a new Latex user and I have a simple document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,onecolumn]{report}

\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,color,colortbl}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=black, linkcolor=black, urlcolor=black, breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bbold}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{arydshln,leftidx,mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[top=52pt, bottom=34pt, left=24pt, right=24pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{thm}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{definition}[thm]{Proposizione}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
%\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbfcal{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

\title{ SIMULATION}

\author{Name\\
    University of Study ,\\
    \texttt{mail@gmail.com}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\section{prova}
\begin{exmp}
    This is the example.
\end{exmp}

\end{document}
```

But when I try to include `\usepackage{mathbbol}`
I have this error:

> Font U/bbold/m/n/14.4=bbold14 at 14.4pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. `\maketitle`

How can I solve it?

Comment: you don't have the mathbbold fonts do you have to load the package? (black board bold is also available with amsfonts)

Comment: Your example works for me. What distribution are you using?

Comment: TeXstudio 2.10.4 and MikTex 2.9 on windows

Comment: I would not use `ansinew` in a new document, better to use a standard encoding such as `latin` or (better) `utf8`

Comment: even with utf8 not work :-@

Comment: The tfm are not preinstalled, but normally miktex should create them on-the-fly. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: the encoding comment is unrelated, but true nevertheless:-) but you didn't say whether you needed those fonts, certainly the example document does not. If specifying a font you have not got  not specifying it or installing the font are always the two options, and obviously not specifying it is easier if you don't need it.

Comment: I have Windows 10x64

Comment: I need of fonts in mathbbol

Comment: the operating system is not really related in any way, if you are using pdftex it uses its own fonts not fonts from the system,

Comment: Also, **subfigure** is obsolete and ought not be used in new documents. Use **subfig** or **subcaption** instead.

Comment: I have solved the problem but I don't know why!!

I have removed %\usepackage{mathbbol} and if I try to use \mathbb{A} in an equation not have problem.

Comment: Whyyy??? mathbbol package is not necessary for use \mathbb{} ????

Comment: `amsfonts` provides `\mathbb`. I'd never even head of `mathbbol` until I saw your question!

Answer (score 1):

Happened to me. Forced the MIKTEX console to update all packages, and the problem is gone.